# Make sure one maven module use the jar file of another module as a dependency when tests are running

Tags: maven

I have the following modules:

- Module A
- Module B ( has a dependency to Module A )
- Module C is a test module ( has a dependency to Module B )

The problem I have is that I have code in Module A that behaves differently on jar files. With the above setup the test is executing on class files. Meaning I don't see the behavior on JAR files. I need to have B as a JAR file when I run the tests in module C but during test phase there is no JARs created.

So I want to make sure that Module B is a JAR file that is used when I run my tests in Module C.

Is it possible?

//mike

Comment: The first question comes to my mind is: What bring that different behaviour related jar not to be jar ? The tests area executed within the appropriate module which are unit tests (running by surefire-plugin). If you need to test in another module this sounds like an integration test which means you can define a dependency to the module B...but this means you have to run integration tests executed by maven-failsafe-plugin ...

Comment: We use a classloader and it seems to have different output if file is from filesystem or in jar.
yes I guess it is more of a integration test and I want to keep my integration test in the same maven project but a different module. Will the fail-safe plugin work on jar files?

Comment: You should write an integration tests and the failsafe-plugin or more accurately based on the life cycle phase it will use the jar file on the test class path... but I don't understand why you insist to keep the integration tests in the same module. As you already wrote the module c is using the module B which means it make either sense to put the IT to module B where it is used or even more make a separate module of it...But why does the usage of a classloader behaves here different? Can you give an example of that?

Comment: I have moved the integration tests to a separate module. I am trying fail-safe plugin.
Now I I have module D that depends on Module B ( I expect module B to be loaded as a jar in classpath. Is it correct?)

I had the following code in Module A

static String getFilePath(String className) {
        ClassLoader systemClassLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
        return systemClassLoader.getResource(className.replace('.', '/') + ".class").toString();

    }

When I executed my unit tests there was no problem to find the path of a class. But got np with jar.

Comment: I tried fail-safe plugin but when I run
mvn verify 
surefire plugin tries to run it as a unit test:
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M6:test (default-test) @ statistics-collector-framework-int-tests ---
[INFO] Using auto detected provider org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider
[INFO]
com.ericsson.commonlibrary.statisticscollectorframework.aspectj.AspectJDeprecatedIT
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.945 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.ericsson.commonlibrary.statisticscollectorframework.aspectj.AspectJDeprecatedI

Comment: You have to follow naming conventions for integration tests ... like AbcIT ... while AbcTest is a unit test...(I recommend to upgrade to 3.0.0-M7)... (Recommend: https://youtu.be/IVwbrhYCLpc)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245689/discussion-between-user256698-and-khmarbaise).